# Python and C interop: Dynamic resizing of ctypes

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes, resize

I'm trying to interop with C in Python, and I have the following function prototype:

```
int testout(unsigned char *test, int *size)
```

The size of the unsigned char is determined by the size parameter.  So I need a way to resize the buffer in Python dynamically to adjust to the size returned from the function call.  This has been very difficult for me to figure out.

From the [Python ctypes manual](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#variable-sized-data-types):

"This is nice and fine, but how would one access the additional elements contained in this array? Since the type still only knows about 4 elements, we get errors accessing other elements:

```
>>> short_array[:]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> short_array[7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
IndexError: invalid index
>>>
```

Another way to use variable-sized data types with ctypes is to use the dynamic nature of Python, and (re-)define the data type after the required size is already known, on a case by case basis."

Great!  I'm getting IndexError:invalid index, just as the example shows.  And they decided not to show how to do this properly!  :)

Does anyone know how to resize a ctype properly?

Here is my example code that works, except for the resizing:

```
from ctypes import *

lib = "test.so"
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib)
print "Testing pointer output"
dll.testout.argtypes = [POINTER(c_ubyte), POINTER(c_int)]
sizeout = c_int(0)
mem = (c_ubyte * 20)() 
dll.testout(mem, byref(sizeout))
print "Sizeout = " + str(sizeout.value)
for i in range(0,sizeout.value):
    print "Item " + str(i) + " = " + str(mem[i])
```

Comment: Not really sure what you want.  The code you have works when used with the source of your previous question, although if you are passing a buffer into a function the function should probably be told how big the buffer is: `sizeout = c_out(20)`.  Are you posting the *exact* code that gives you an error?

Comment: Mark, this code does work.  But only if size <= 20.  That is the issue.  How do I resize the data to receive something of unknown size?

Comment: Since your function doesn't take an `unsigned char**` it can't return a buffer it allocated itself of arbirtrary size.  Your function is passing in a buffer of known size (and should pass the size as well, with `size = c_int(20)`.  Then the called function can check that the buffer is big enough to hold the result, and update `size` with the amount used.

Comment: Thank you Mark.  C, and pointers, are not my strong suit.  So the way I'm handling this in my function is just fine.  Thank you.

Comment: You can also say `size=xxxxx` and `mem=(c_ubyte*size)()` to allocate buffers of varying sizes.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the size required until calling the function.  The strange thing, though, is that I CAN resize the buffer if I call the function within C itself.  I have made a test C function where I send in a 2 byte array and return a 5 byte array successfully.  You can see that code as well in my previous post.  So it seems that I should be able to with Python.

Comment: That's undefined behavior.  If five bytes are written to a two-byte array, you are writing over memory you don't own and corrupting other parts of the program, which might not be immediately apparent in a small program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of what we were discussing.  This code expects the caller to allocate the buffer.

#### Test code (Windows)

```
// IN: test=pre-allocated buffer.
// IN: size=size of pre-allocated buffer.
// RETURNS: 0 and size set to required size.
//          1 and size set to size used.
__declspec(dllexport) int testout(void *pdata, int *psize)
{
    unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *)pdata;

    if (*psize < 5)
    {
        *psize = 5; // set size required
        return 0;  // fail
    }

    p[0] = 123;
    p[1] = 255;
    p[2] = 237;
    p[3] = 12;
    p[4] = 222;
    *psize = 5; // indicate size used

    return 1;  // pass
}
```

#### Python

```
from ctypes import *

test = CDLL('test')
size = c_int(0)
test.testout.argtypes=[c_void_p,POINTER(c_int)]
print "Result of NULL pointer and zero size:",test.testout(None,byref(size))
print "Returned size:",size.value
mem = (c_ubyte * 2)()
size = c_int(sizeof(mem))
print "sizeof(mem):",size.value
print "Result of small buffer:",test.testout(byref(mem),byref(size))
print "Returned size:",size.value
mem = (c_ubyte * size.value)()
print "Result of exact size buffer:",test.testout(byref(mem),byref(size))
print "Returned size:",size.value
for i in range(size.value):
    print mem[i]
mem = (c_ubyte * 20)()
size = c_int(20)
print "Result of bigger buffer:",test.testout(byref(mem),byref(size))
print "Returned size:",size.value
for i in range(size.value):
    print mem[i]
```

#### Output

```
Result of NULL pointer and zero size: 0
Returned size: 5
sizeof(mem): 2
Result of small buffer: 0
Returned size: 5
Result of exact size buffer: 1
Returned size: 5
123
255
237
12
222
Result of bigger buffer: 1
Returned size: 5
123
255
237
12
222
```

Answer (score 1):

If you receive a pointer from C, you can index the corresponding ctypes pointer just like a C pointer.

If you need to allocate the array in Python, you can create the ctypes array type of appropriate size dynamically.

Comment: Janne, do you mind modifying this code to show what you mean.  This is my 'working code'.  Everything is working but dynamic resizing of the array.